# How can I make a code snippet and add it to the Snippet intellisense in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, code-snippets

I'm curious if this is even possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible:
Here's a link showing how to do it: http://en.csharp-online.net/Visual_Studio_Code_Snippets%E2%80%94Creating_Snippets_Manually

Here's the official page on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Sure, I use this tool.

http://www.codeplex.com/SnippetEditor

Answer (score 0):

You Need to install Code snippet Designer 
You download the snippet following link
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-2795.SnippetDesigner

After install restart your visual studio and open new file in Snippet
after open select you language (c#,Html,C++, e.g...) 
and save your particular language in visual studio location
C:\Users\hamza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Code Snippets\JavaScript\My Code Snippets

this is my system where i store my snippets and get shortcut key
CTRL+K+X